# how to give classpath for a property file using spring

Tags: spring

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:src/main/resources/template/datafields.properties");
```

Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your file is actually not in the application classpath. Looking at your folder paths I am assuming that you have a maven project structure and your properties file is present within resources directory. When your project is compiled, everything inside the  resources directory is at the root of the classpath along with your compiled java classes. So you should instead use

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("template/datafields.properties");
```

Classpath resource loads resources from the application classpath, so you need to be aware what all directories/jar files  are in your classpath and their directory structure to successfully load resources.